# Different result on same code

Tags: javascript

Duplicate of

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Sorry all for duplicate and still thanks for responding!

Comment: Don't use that `json` variable outside of the `then`.  You have to be async all the way down.

Comment: Use callback fn?

Comment: Use await/async?

Comment: welcome to asynchronous programming. You are trying to eat a delivery pizza before it gets to your house.

Comment: The first one works because you're artificially including a delay (the time it takes you to paste the code), which allows the asynchronous operation to complete.

Comment: In your first example your kind of creating an artificial delay, if you had done a setTimeout it would have done the same.  In the second example, you fetch & parseInt are in essence going to run at the same time..

Comment: `So, got a wierd issue going on` not really.. :)

Comment: So what's going on here, is that nothing in the .then() calls is going to execute until api-call returns results. That code is registered as a 'callback' for when there's data, and won't be executed until then. In the meantime, everything after your catch is getting executed already. The 'json' variable hasn't been set yet, so is going to have value 'undefined'.

Comment: "In your first example your kind of creating an artificial delay, if you had done a setTimeout it would have done the same. In the second example, you fetch & parseInt are in essence going to run at the same time.. – Keith 12 hours ago "

Ah, I See! Will work on that. Thank you and all others for answering!